# Korn Shell - env, printenv, export - How to get CRLF as a delimiter

Tags: environment-variables, ksh

This seems simple, but I can't find anything on how to do this : I'm basically using a KSH variable to build my email body text.  In an error/exception situation I want to dump the env/printenv/export as well using '\n' as a delimiter.

```
if (( $status != 0 ))
then
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n"
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n\tBatch Process\t: ${BATCHPROCESS}"
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n\tEnvironment\t: ${ENVTEXT}"
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n\tDate/Time\t: ${STARTDATETIME}"
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n\nRuntime:"
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n$(env)"
    echo -e $MESSAGE >>  ${MAILFILE1}
    mail -s"FAILURE - ${SUBJECT} " $MAILLIST <  ${MAILFILE1}
```

So, according to the documentation on env/printenv/export, it's already using LF as a delimiter, but when I receive the email, it's just one big BLOCK of text :

```
Runtime:

Runtime:
```

What I want is each variable on a separate line :

```
Runtime : 
ACCESSDB=[Sybase-Database]
ACCESSSRV=[Sybase-Server]
...etc...
```

Is there anyway to force a '\n' in place of the LF currently being used?

UPDATE : I'm using sed -s 's/$/\r\n/g' and it's formatting the env output, but now the entire email body text gets sent as an attachment :

```
if (( $status != 0 ))
then
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n"
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n\tBatch Process\t: ${BATCHPROCESS}"
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n\tEnvironment\t: ${ENVTEXT}"
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n\tDate/Time\t: ${STARTDATETIME}"
    env | sort | sed 's/$/\r\n/g' > ${TEMPFILES}/env.txt
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n\nRuntime:"
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n$(cat ${TEMPFILES}/env.txt)"

    echo -e "$MESSAGE" >>  ${MAILFILE1}
    mail -s"FAILURE - ${SUBJECT} " $MAILLIST <  ${MAILFILE1}
```

Any ideas?  I'm thinking it's some kinda mail setting on max email size, but I'm a Java programmer more than a shell scripter...

CLOSE SOLUTION : Turns out the \r\n was causing the attachment issue [https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1136493].  So I used sed -s 's/$/\n/g' and this is pretty close to what I wanted except the env is output using double lines :

```
if (( $status != 0 ))
then
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n"
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n\tBatch Process\t: ${BATCHPROCESS}"
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n\tEnvironment\t: ${ENVTEXT}"
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n\tDate/Time\t: ${STARTDATETIME}"
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n\nRuntime:"
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n$(env | sort | sed 's/$/\n/g')"

    echo -e "$MESSAGE" >>  ${MAILFILE1}
    mail -s"FAILURE - ${SUBJECT} " $MAILLIST <  ${MAILFILE1}
```

Produces output :

```
Runtime:
ACCESSDB=[Sybase-Database]

ACCESSSRV=[Sybase-server]

ARCHIVEDB=[Sybase-Database]

ASBIN=[Directory-Path]
```

FINAL SOLUTION : Implemented markp's fix and then just took out my sed -s stuff and it works correctly :

```
if (( $status != 0 ))
then
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n"
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n\tBatch Process\t: ${BATCHPROCESS}"
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n\tEnvironment\t: ${ENVTEXT}"
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n\tDate/Time\t: ${STARTDATETIME}"
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n\nRuntime:"
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE}\n$(env | sort)"

    echo -e "$MESSAGE" >>  ${MAILFILE1}
    mail -s"FAILURE - ${SUBJECT} " $MAILLIST <  ${MAILFILE1}
```

tia,  adym

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping $MESSAGES in double quotes to maintain special formatting, white space, etc:

```
echo -e "$MESSAGE" >>  ${MAILFILE1}
```

---

Whether or not you get what you expect with the 'echo -e' and 'mail -s' commands will depend on which version of said commands you're using.

Comment: markp, turns out you are correct.  I needed to do this as well as take out my sed -s stuff.  Thank you!  adym

Answer (score 1):

As @markp correctly observes, your use of

```
echo $MESSAGE >>$MAILFILE1
```

will substitute the string $MESSAGE as several white space separated arguments to echo, and echo will simply put a space between arguments. This is similar to typing

```
$ echo a     b               c
a b c
```

I in your place would do it thus

```
 echo "$MESSAGE"                         >>$MAILFILE1
 echo "Batch Process:\t $BATCHPROCESS"   >>$MAILFILE1
 echo "Environment: ...."                >>$MAKEFILE1
```

Or with an inline document:

```
   cat <<FINE >>$MAKEFILE1
$MESSAGE
Batch Process:      $BATCHPROCESS
Environment: ....
....
FINE
```